# Global variable/fade out not triggering

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I'm using GameMaker 2.

Trying to get a piece of code to work that when an alarm hits 12 seconds, it changes a global variable within the object which then triggers the object to carry out it's normal process - fading the screen out to black. However it isn't working and I can't figure out what isn't working.

This is the code I have at the moment;

Create:

```
variable_timer = 100;

global.fadeoutsimilarities = 0;

alarm[0] = room_speed * 12;
```

Step:

```
variable_timer-=1;
```

Alarm 0:

```
global.fadeoutsimilarities = global.fadeoutsimilarities + 1;
```

Draw:

```
if (global.fadeoutsimilarities)
{
   draw_set_color(c_black);
   draw_set_alpha(variable_timer/30);
}

else {}
```

Any ideas on what's preventing it from fading out to black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variebla `global.fadeoutsimilarities = 0;` it is a numeric variable and when placing `global.fadeoutsimilarities = global.fadeoutsimilarities + 1;` you are telling him to add up to 1, then I will be 1 then 2, 3, 4, ... and so, and in event draw you place the conditional `if (global.fadeoutsimilarities)` which means `if global.fadeoutsimilarities = 1` it will be black, but this will only happen during a frame in a blink, the solution is to `change the values ​​of global.fadeoutsimilarities by true and false,` it would look like this:

Create:

```
variable_timer = 10;

global.fadeoutsimilarities = false;

alarm [0] = room_speed * 12;
```

Step:

```
//without code
```

Alarm 0:

```
global.fadeoutsimilarities = true;
variable_timer -=1;
```

Draw:

```
if (global.fadeoutsimilarities)
{
   draw_set_color (c_black);
   draw_set_alpha (variable_timer / 10);
}
```

if you have doubts write me
www.facebook.com/BusyClown

If I help you with something, give me a +1